# jQuery clicks events on flow to add/remove rows from table

Tags: jquery, events, html-table, row

I add with jQuery dynamically on click new rows to my table, on the other hand I have a function which can remove rows on button click. My problem that dynamically added rows cannot be deleted if I try to delete after when I added.

```
//adding new row to table
    $('button#addRow.btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var rowCount = $('#feeds tr').length;
            $('#feeds > tbody:last').append(//here comes tr html)};

//removing rows from table

    $("tr td .delete").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("tr").remove()
    });
```

Comment: You need to use event delegation, see the [documentation for `on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: are you adding delete class in new added td?

Comment: delete class is there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the table rows are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$('#feeds').on('click', '.delete', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

This will attach your event to any `.delete` button within the `#feeds` element, 
reducing the scope of having to check the whole `document` element tree and increasing efficiency.

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, as it is the correct answer, +1

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something like this in your tr html:

```
<tr>
    // whatever ...

    <td>
        <input type="button" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove();" value="Delete" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

That button will remove the row which it belongs to.